# "sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg)" statement works on 5.1 and 6.1 simulator, but not on iPhone 4 device

Tags: xcode

I'm newbie.  I didn't think I was the only one with this issue, but all the other problems I viewed didn't seem to cover this particular issue.  I'm just trying to update a table in sqlite see below code.  This code works in both 5.1 and 6.1 simulators, but when I run it on my device (iPhone 4 - iOS 6.1), the "`sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);`" statement (fifth statement from the bottom) fails the error "if" statement (fourth statement from the bottom and gives me "Error while updating. cannot commit - no transaction is active" NLog statement (third statement from the bottom).  If someone can advise me as to what I am doing wrong I would be very much appreciative.  Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    int rowCount = indexPath.row;
    Game *game = [self.thegames objectAtIndex:rowCount];
    cell.textLabel.text = game.GameDate;


    NSString* str3=[game.GameDate substringToIndex:4];

    NSString * Selected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"You Selected Game - ", str3];
    displayLabel.text = Selected;


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sportretortdatab2.sqlite"];

    NSString* str1 = displayLabel.text;
    NSString *str2 = [str1 substringFromIndex: [str1 length] - 4];

    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;
           if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)    
    {
        NSString* sql= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE ArchievedGameDate Set GameDate = \"%@\"", str2];


        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, [sql cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    char* errmsg;
    sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
        NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
    sqlite3_close(database);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with:

```
if(sqlite3_step(updateStmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
```

or

```
int step = sqlite3_step(updateStmt);
if(step != SQLITE_DONE)
```

and without:

```
sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
```

is this really necessary in this context? Did you start transaction? I guess sqlite is in autocommit mode but you can check with the sqlite3_get_autocommit() interface. It returns non-zero or zero if the given database connection is or is not in autocommit mode, respectively. Autocommit mode is on by default. Autocommit mode is disabled by a BEGIN statement. Autocommit mode is re-enabled by a COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

and put the all SQLite functions into the statement:

```
if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

and I also hope the "db" in this prepare first parameter is "database" in the active code because it means you are working on two database instance.

```
sqlite3_prepare(db, [sql cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to view my issue.  However, you're suggestions didn't work for me.  I noticed that when I made your suggested changes, I attempted to Archive.  That failed.  It the Archive also failed without making your suggested changes.  I'm looking into why that is happening.  Any ideas?  Thanks again for yor time.

Comment: In sqlite3_prepare you should try to give the length of the SQL statement not -1. Maybe it misses the zero terminator.

Comment: Hi DebugMedve,  I changed a few things around, based on re-re-re-reading your comments.  did a little/lot more research on this topic and replace the above code with the following (see below). It works great in the iPhone 5.1 simulator, but when i put the code into the iPhone device, I get "2013-02-23 00:07:39.023 TableView[1712:907] Problem with prepare statement:  no such table: Games".  I checked everything and the Games table is there.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry but I used only the SQLite C API, so I have finite ideas.
1: You selected the correct database file, but the table does not exist.
2: You selected another database
3: Your device runs bad version of sqlite. (I'm not sure you can, but try to upgrade or reinstall it)
4: From some sqlite interface there are another version like sqlite3_prepare_v2 they are recommended for the new programs. (I don't know the iPhones use the same C,C++ API but it's just an idea.) Good luck :]